# Alon-Füredi for homogeneous polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, additive-combinatorics

A [theorem of Alon and Füredi](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/Publications/Covering%20the%20cube%20by%20affine%20hyperplanes.pdf) says that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, nonempty subsets of the field $\mathbb F$, and if a polynomial $P(x,y)\in\mathbb F[x,y]$ vanishes on all, but exactly one point of the grid $A\times B$, then
$\deg P\ge |A|+|B|-2$.

Can one improve this bound given that $P$ is homogeneous?

> What is the smallest possible degree of a *homogeneous* polynomial $P(x,y)$ vanishing on all, but exactly one point of the grid $A\times B$?

The underlying field $\mathbb F$ can be assumed to have characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general homogeneity does not improve the bound. Take $A=\{1,q,q^2,\ldots,q^{a-1}\}$, $B=\{1,q,q^2,\ldots,q^{b-1}\}$, $f(x,y)=\prod_{i=-(b-1)}^{a-2}(x-q^iy)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $0\notin B$, then $$F(x,y) = y^n \left(c_n \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n+\cdots+c_0\right).$$ Let $S=\{x/y:\ x\in A,y\in B\}.$ For $F$ to vanish on all the points of $A\times B$ except $1$, we must have that the one variable polynomial $$P(z)=c_n z^n+\cdots +c_0$$ vanishes on all the points of $S$ except $1$, and so $\deg F \geq |S|-1$.

In general, the Scherk-Kemperman Theorem states that $$|S|\geq |A|+|B|-\min_{c \in S}|A\cap cB|$$ (thank you Fedor for pointing this out) and equality is obtained if $A$ and $B$ are geometric progressions. Hence we will not have an improvement to the bound in the specific case where $A$ and $B$ are geometric progressions.

Comment: We do not always have $|S|\geqslant |A|+|B|-1$ for arbitrary $A, B$. But we do if a certain element in $S$ has unique representation as $a/b$ for $a\in A, b\in B$ (this is a theorem of Kemperman and Scherk), and this is exactly our case.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you, I've updated the answer with the statement of the Scherk-Kemperman Theorem